# Low battery temp and wont charge galaxy note 5 after phone got wet

Tags: battery

The top of my Note 5 was wet, I dried it off and placed the phone in rice. 2 days later it began working again, 2 days after that I received the error msg that charging is paused due to battery temp too low. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

It depends. If this is a phone where the temperature sensor is within the battery, the battery can simply be replaced, but that does not guarantee that this is the only issue. If the sensor is in the motherboard or another piece, the phone is likely permanently damaged and will need to be replaced.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the charger port in service centers or try to keep the phone in normal temp.